# How to store a JSON object in couchbase using springboot

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase

I am new to spring boot and I am developing a simple spring boot API to store data to a couchbase db. Storing JSON objects have different formats.Is there any suitable method to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried Spring Data? https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-couchbase

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase has given support for the JAVA SDK's that can help you easily integrate the couchbase api's and access the couchbase server to perform CRUD operation's here is the tutorial available : [JAVA SDK](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.1/tutorial.html)
And also please take a look at this blog [couchbase with Spring Boot sample example](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/)